# How to make a case sensitive code for file upload by name

Tags: php, mysql

So i have more than one image to upload, each one being a new line in my mysql table:

I use this code for file input with name="profile"

```
if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
    echo 'Please choose a file!';
}else {
    $allowed= array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')       
    $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
    $file_exts = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_extn = strtolower(end($file_exts));
    $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
    if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
        change_image($session_user_id, 1, $file_temp, $file_extn);
        header('Location: galery.php');
        exit();
    }else {
        echo 'Incorrect file type . allowed files are : ';
        echo implode(", ", $allowed);
```

(change_image) function makes this MySql query

```
$sql = "UPDATE `art_$id` SET `path` = \"" . $file_path . "\" WHERE `row` = " . (int)$row;
```

But i want to repeat this code for profil1, profil2... and change accordingly the row (example : profil4 would change row 4 ), without having to repeat this code for each file='name'.

How would i go about that?

Comment: are you trying to multiple upload through these script??

Comment: use input name something like that: name="files[]" in your html. That means this is a multiple file upload. Then you can foreach through your $_FILES['files'] in your php script, and do the job with each files

Comment: Can you add code what is in the `change_image` function

Comment: @Mitul here is the code for change_image :

     function change_image($id, $row, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
 $file_path = 'image/art/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' .                                                                           $file_extn;
 move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
 $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "artlibra");
 $sql = "UPDATE `art_$id` SET `path` = \"" . $file_path . "\" WHERE `row` = " . (int)$row;

 $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
 
}

Im sorry it is all bundled up .

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of your form have "how many fields as of file and what they are named??" . Following code will upload them one by one ..Check it

```
 $rowid=1;
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$image_uploaded)
    {
    if (isset($image_uploaded[$key]) === true) {
    if (empty($image_uploaded[$key]['name']) === true) {
        echo 'Please choose a file!';
    }else {
        $allowed= array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')       
        $file_name = $image_uploaded[$key]['name'];
        $file_exts = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_extn = strtolower(end($file_exts));
        $file_temp = $image_uploaded[$key]['tmp_name'];
        if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
            change_image($session_user_id, $rowid++, $file_temp, $file_extn);
            //change as you need
            header('Location: galery.php');
            exit();
        }else {
            echo 'Incorrect file type . allowed files are : ';
            echo implode(", ", $allowed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, as i have a specific submit button for each form and don't wont to validate all forms at once i used this code :

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= 9; $row++) {
if (isset($_FILES["profile" . $row]) === true) {
if (empty($_FILES["profile" . $row]['name']) === true) {
    echo 'Please choose a file!';
}else {
    $allowed= array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    $file_name = $_FILES["profile" . $row]['name'];
    $file_exts = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_extn = strtolower(end($file_exts));
    $file_temp = $_FILES["profile" . $row]['tmp_name'];

    if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
        change_image($session_user_id, $row, $file_temp, $file_extn);
        //header('Location: galery.php');
        //exit();
    }else {
        echo 'Incorrect file type . allowed files are : ';
        echo implode(", ", $allowed);

          }



}

}
}
```

And for file input i use name="profile1",name="profile2",....,name="profile9"(for this case).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the code which will add 1,2,3 at end of the image file name
Bellow function will check the file exist in dir or not and return new file name now you can use the function before `change_image` function call and get new file name and pass new name in `change_image` for save.

```
function getFileName($fileName, $file_extn){
    $fileNameWithoutExt = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $i = 1;
    while(!file_exists('image/art/' . $fileName)){
          $fileName = $fileNameWithoutExt . $i . "." . $file_extn;
          $i++;
    }
    return  $fileName;
}
```